# Fatal error: Call to a member function executeQuery() on a non-object

Tags: php, mongodb, google-api

I tried to implement the Google Login with PHP and MongoDB. Whenever I try to execute `$manager->executeQuery`, I get Fatal error that states it cannot be executed.

```
$cursor = $manager->executeQuery($this->dbName.'.'.$this->userTbl, $prevQuery);
```

I have no ideas how to debug this programs. Here is my code sample:

```
class User {

    private $dbHost     = "localhost:27017";
    private $dbName     = "Demo";
    private $userTbl    = 'google_users';


    function __construct(){
        //Connecting to MongoDB
        try {

            $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager( 'mongodb://'. $this->dbHost ); 
        }
        catch (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) {

            echo $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }
    }


    function checkUser($userData = array()){
        if(!empty($userData)){
            //Check whether user data already exists in database

            $filter = ['oauth_uid' => $userData['oauth_uid'], 'oauth_provider' => $userData['oauth_provider']];
            $prevQuery = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter);
            $user_count=0;

            try {

                $cursor = $manager->executeQuery($this->dbName.'.'.$this->userTbl, $prevQuery);

                // Iterate over all matched documents
                foreach ($cursor as $document) {
                    $user_count++; //will return 0 if user doesn't exist
                }

            } catch (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage(), "\n";
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is `$manager` defined in that method? It does not look like it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to make the `$manager` created in the constructor a property of the class so you can use it anywhere in the class

```
class User {

    private $dbHost     = "localhost:27017";
    private $dbName     = "Demo";
    private $userTbl    = 'google_users';


    function __construct(){
        //Connecting to MongoDB
        try {

            $this->manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager( 'mongodb://'. $this->dbHost ); 
        //  ^^^^^ make a class property
        }
        catch (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) {

            echo $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }
    }


    function checkUser($userData = array()){
        if(!empty($userData)){
            //Check whether user data already exists in database

            $filter = ['oauth_uid' => $userData['oauth_uid'], 'oauth_provider' => $userData['oauth_provider']];
            $prevQuery = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter);
            $user_count=0;

            try {

                $cursor = $this->manager->executeQuery($this->dbName.'.'.$this->userTbl, $prevQuery);
                //        ^^^^^ reuse the class property

                // Iterate over all matched documents
                foreach ($cursor as $document) {
                    $user_count++; //will return 0 if user doesn't exist
                }

            } catch (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage(), "\n";
            }  
        }
    }
}
```